# Bootstrap resize issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a login form that is loaded in a bootstrap model. Im using the normal sized modal and not the large one. The Login form is formatted so that at the left side there are 2 input fields and a login button, the right side should contain other options to login.

The way i have my page layout out is as follow:

```
container
  row
    col-sm-6
    col-sm-6
```

The problem is that the models width is around 600 pixels which makes my login page go "responsive" and instead of placing the col-sm-6 next to each other it places them under each other.

From my understaning i should be able to get this working by doing something with the:

```
 @media (min-width: 768px) {
      .container {
        width: 550px;
      }
    }
```

But above just didnt work at all.

Any ideas,please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

600 pixels falls under the `xs device` category. You simply need to change your layout to this:

```
container
  row
    col-xs-6
    col-xs-6
```

If you have not read about the device sizes, you can do so [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options). You can also add multiple grid classes to each div and the layout will be controlled depending on the size.

**Example**

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12">
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12">
</div>
```

The above will have 2 columns side by side on an `xs` device, but will be stacked on a `sm` device.

Comment: Wow, im not sure why i didnt try this since ive read that a gazillion times. This did the trick though thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use inline forms

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">

</form>
```

Comment: This is incorrect, you cannot use inline forms unless the viewport is at least 768px wide. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

Answer (score 0):

Try to use combination of classes:

like `.col-xs-6, .col-sm-6, .col-md-6, .col-lg-6`

Comment: `.col-xs-6, .col-sm-6, .col-md-6, .col-lg-6` is exactly equivalent to `.col-xs-6`, except more unnecessarily verbose & complex.